# Generating an uber/fat/shade sources-jar (and javadoc-jar) using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Does anyone know how to make a uber/fat/shade sources-jar (and javadoc-jar) using Gradle?

The generated Jar should not only contain the sources of the current project but also the sources of it's dependencies. I have been looking at, among others, [a vanilla way](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/) and a way using the [Shadow Plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). Both work great at creating a normal uber/fat/shade jar, but none of them seems to support a way to create a sources-jar.

Comment: can explain the difference between uber/flat/shaded jar and sources-jar? because you want a jar with all of the dependencies and both of them contain all of the dependencies in a single jar.

Comment: The sources-jar contains (amongst others) the .java files. While a uber/flat/shaded jar contains the .class files and it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Shadow Plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/). In Maven it is called shade plugin. Does same thing. It produces an executable uber jar!